# Can o-phenanthroline be used as a complexing agent for lead(II)?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, analytical-chemistry, coordination-compounds

I’ve been trying to find a method to perform a spectrophotometric analysis to determine lead concentration (on the ppm level). This would require some chelator capable of forming a coloured complex with lead in the aqueous phase.

Fe(II) ion can bind to *o*-phenanthroline to form an orange colour (with deeper hues based on the present concentration of iron irons).  I was wondering if lead(II) can too complex in the same way.

Note: The source of lead is $\ce{Pb(NO3)2}.$ This means some nitrate ions will be present in solution after dissociation of this chemical in water.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are numerous known lead(II) *o*-phenanthroline complexes with thiocyanate, perchlorate and bulkier organic ligands.
As for nitrate, Bytheway et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10.1071/CH9961099)] reported synthesis (from lead(II) nitrate in methanol) and crystal structure of bis((1,10-phenanthroline)-(nitrato-*O*,*O*'))-lead(II):

[image: rystal structure of bis((1,10-phenanthroline)-(nitrato-O,O'))-lead(II)]
**Figure 1**. crystal structure of $\ce{[(phen)2Pb(NO3)2]}$ ([CCDC: 1246661, CSD: RAQMAX](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Ccdcid=RAQMAX&DatabaseToSearch=Published)).

Unfortunately, there is no UV-Vis/NIR spectra available.
Harrowfield et al. [[2](https://doi.org/10.1071/CH9961029), p. 1030] reported that the crystals are colorless, which likely eliminates visible region of detection.

#### References

1. Bytheway, I.; Engelhardt, L.; Harrowfield, J.; Kepert, D.; Miyamae, H.; Patrick, J.; Skelton, B.; Soudi, A.; White, A. Lewis-Base Adducts of Lead(II) Compounds. XIII. Synthetic, Structural and Theoretical Studies of Some 2:1 Adducts of 1,10-Phenanthroline With Lead(II) Oxoanion Salts. A*ust. J. Chem.* **1996**, 49 (10), 1099. DOI: [10.1071/CH9961099](https://doi.org/10.1071/CH9961099).
2. Harrowfield, J.; Miyamae, H.; Skelton, B.; Soudi, A.; White, A. Lewis-Base Adducts of Lead(II) Compounds. VII. Synthetic and Structural Studies of Some 1:1 Adducts of Linear Polyamines With Lead(II) Nitrate. *Aust. J. Chem.* **1996**, 49 (10), 1029. DOI: [10.1071/CH9961029](https://doi.org/10.1071/CH9961029).